# Using scale and translate on animated element messes up the transform-origin

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Trying to create an animated mic component using the Web Speech API which I'll toggle based whether it's listening or not. While it's on listening mode, I want to show a animated ripple effect which is implemented on scaling it via keyframes. I'm also positioning the ripple pseudo element absolutely in center for which I'm using `translate` too which disrupts its `transform-origin`. I tried setting it in center but it isn't working. Any idea why?

```css
.mic-container{
  width: 52px;
  height: 166px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #6593c3;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
button{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
button::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: scale(0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: center center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #6593c3;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 1.5s all ease;
  animation: ripple 1.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    trasform: scale(1.2);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.8);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2.4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='mic-container'>
  <button>
    <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M15 20.7129C17.5605 20.7129 19.6289 18.5156 19.6289 15.8203V6.76758C19.6289 4.07227 17.5605 1.875 15 1.875C12.4395 1.875 10.3711 4.07227 10.3711 6.76758V15.8203C10.3711 18.5156 12.4395 20.7129 15 20.7129Z" fill="#4976A6"/>
<path d="M21.5039 11.25V15.9199C21.5039 19.4473 18.5859 22.3184 15.0586 22.3184C11.5312 22.3184 8.61328 19.4473 8.61328 15.9199V11.25H7.5V15.9199C7.5 19.8574 10.6055 23.1035 14.5312 23.3906V27.0703H10.2539V28.125H19.6875V27.0703H15.6445V23.3906C19.5117 23.1035 22.5 19.8574 22.5 15.9199V11.25H21.5039Z" fill="#6593C3"/>
</svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use  `transform-origin: 0 0;`

> By default, the origin of a transform is center.

[transform-origin CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#wikiArticle)

You also have a typo here. it is `transform` not `trasform`

```
 0% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
```

```css
.mic-container {
  width: 52px;
  height: 166px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #6593c3;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: scale(0) translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #6593c3;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 1.5s all ease;
  animation: ripple 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.8) translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2.4) translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='mic-container'>
  <button>
    <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M15 20.7129C17.5605 20.7129 19.6289 18.5156 19.6289 15.8203V6.76758C19.6289 4.07227 17.5605 1.875 15 1.875C12.4395 1.875 10.3711 4.07227 10.3711 6.76758V15.8203C10.3711 18.5156 12.4395 20.7129 15 20.7129Z" fill="#4976A6"/>
<path d="M21.5039 11.25V15.9199C21.5039 19.4473 18.5859 22.3184 15.0586 22.3184C11.5312 22.3184 8.61328 19.4473 8.61328 15.9199V11.25H7.5V15.9199C7.5 19.8574 10.6055 23.1035 14.5312 23.3906V27.0703H10.2539V28.125H19.6875V27.0703H15.6445V23.3906C19.5117 23.1035 22.5 19.8574 22.5 15.9199V11.25H21.5039Z" fill="#6593C3"/>
</svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the point that I need to include ```translate``` in the keyframes too. But why does it jitter at 50% scale?

Comment: Because the translate didn't exist in the animation and you were overriding the transform using the scale only. That's my understanding

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your `@keyframes` animation, you are writing lines of `transform` as such `transform: scale(1.2);`, thus removing the translate part that you set previously.

You will also need to set the original element like this:

```
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(3) translate(-50%, -50%);
```

To have it work properly, you would have to keep the `translate` part in your `transform` declaration, like this :

```
@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    trasform: scale(1.2) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.8) translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2.4) translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
```